# Can I utilize ARKit's camera tracking without anchoring the pointOfView to the camera itself?

Tags: ios, scenekit, ios11, arkit, skybox

I'm trying to utilize the benefits of ARKit's camera tracking for a game, but without actually having to position the player at the position of the camera.

Does ARKit provide a way to do so, or am I forced to use a different way of camera/device tracking which is as good as the one provided by ARKit?

Comment: ARKit always takes over positioning/orienting the SceneKit camera in ARSCNView. Depending on what you mean by "without actually having to position the player at the position of the camera" there might be other options open to you.

Comment: What I intend to do is to position the SceneKit camera at a fixed position all through the session, and position the "device camera" where the AR camera tracking would position it in the space (so the player sees an object that represents the camera moving in the space relatively to his/her position).

Comment: So you're looking for a "not quite AR" experience, where the video feed isn't displayed in the background, but instead you're displaying your own 3D world, and using ARKit's tracking to position content within it? If so I probably have an answer, but want to be sure of the question first. 

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. I managed to actually achieve it by adding a new `pointOfView` to the scene, but I wonder whether there's a solution that doesn't even involve ARKit (e.g device position tracking not via AR tracking).